# How to download a file via URL from VueJS and save it to a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use it in VueJS as below code via the URL of a file that is made public in AWS S3 or Google Drive.

```
...
const file = AWS S3 or Google Drive File URL
...
```

How can this be done?

Comment: We need more information. How exactly does AWS/Google provide the file? Is it an API endpoint, which sends the file content? Is the file content displayed, when visiting the URL?

Comment: Not the path I get through Axios etc. It's simply a static URL like this: ex)
 https://test.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/event/file

Comment: try `window.open(the_url)`. If using AWS you need to make sure the `ResponseContentDisposition` header is present

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a Blob.

```
const response = await this.$axios.get(`documents?s3-key=${s3Key}`)
const awsS3Response = await axios.get(response.data, { responseType: 'blob' })
const blob = new Blob([awsS3Response.data])
const link = document.createElement('a')
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
link.download = s3Key
link.click()
URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
```

`response.data` is a signed url

This is how I created the signed url in my API.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' })

async function getDocument({ s3Key }) {
  return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: 'lqdc2documents',
    Key: s3Key,
    Expires: 60,
  })
}
```

Comment: Thaks it's helm to me

Comment: How did you manage to use aws-sdk to vuejs since we get Node module not found

Comment: @Shulz: `yarn add aws-sdk` and `import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';`